# bash: call function with variables vs function with arguments

Tags: bash, function

Lets take for example next function:

version 1 - with variables:

```
 backup () {
 for arname in `arname_f`
 do
   slapcat -b "$setnames" -l "$bkdir"/"$ardate"_"$arname".ldif || exit 1
 done
 }
```

and run it just with code:

```
 backup;
```

version 2 - with positional arguments:

```
 backup () {
 for arname in `arname_f`
 do
   slapcat -b "$1" -l "$2"/"$3"_"$4".ldif || exit 1
 done
 }
```

and let's run with such code:

```
 backup $setnames $bkdir $ardate $arname;
```

Is there any difference in this slants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has nothing to do with `Bash` as such.

The #1 is the example of "Spaghetti" coding style (global variables) hated by most professionals and simply sane people. It will eventually cause a major problem when someone somewhere changes the parameter and the function starts misbehaving, and you won't have a clue of who/what has changed what where.

The #2 is close to how I would do it. Though, of cause, there may well be a valid reason to prefer #1, it depends.